# TabHost not working with higher Android Versions

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Can anyone be able to solve, why this simple code is not working in higher version of android ? The MainActivity.java looks like this.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabHost tabHost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        //Tab 1
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab One");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 2
        spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab Two");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 3
        spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab Three");
        host.addTab(spec);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And the activity_main.xml is as below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffc916"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="This is tab 1" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#da8200"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="This is tab 2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#5b89ff"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="This is tab 3" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, the final app is crashing at the startup. Really, Im clue less in finding the error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it is crashing, please add logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Simple Code is running smoothly here is your edited code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class TabTest extends Activity {

    TabHost tabHost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_test);

        TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        //Tab 1
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab One");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 2
        spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab Two");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 3
        spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("Tab Three");
        host.addTab(spec);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So the problem was only with AppCompatActivity ?? Can you please see my another query posted here 
                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200150/dynamic-tabhost-crashing-in-higher-version-of-android-but-working-fine-with-2-3?noredirect=1#comment75425576_44200150